# oracle sql query returning no rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

im having two tables customer and customerType. i want to get the count of VVIP customers from customerType table having booking dates from 1/24/2016 to 1/27/2016.
My query:

```
select count(distinct f.CUSTOMER_ID) as agg from customerType f JOIN 
customer t ON f.CUSTOMERID=t.CUSTOMERID where 
f.type='VVIP' and t.BookingDate BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('10/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/02/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

[image]

Comment: What is BookingDate column type ?

Comment: BookingDate column type is Date

Comment: if you need `dates from 1/24/2016 to 1/27/2016`, then why your query have : `BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('10/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/02/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')`

Comment: sorry to say that is just sample data..

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct f.CUSTOMER_ID) as agg from customerType f 
INNER join JOIN customer t ON f.CUSTOMERID=t.CUSTOMERID where 
f.type='VVIP' and t.BookingDate BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('01/24/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01/27/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Try above query .

Hope this will helps.

Comment: What it's returning?

Comment: No rows selected

Comment: What is the column type of `BookingDate `?

Answer (score 0):

basically i am working on mysql but there are not much difference between mysql,oracle so please try below query this will defiantly helps you

`select count(f.CUSTOMER_ID) as agg from customerType f INNER JOIN 
customer t ON f.CUSTOMERID=t.CUSTOMERID WHERE 
f.type='VVIP' and t.BookingDate BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('10/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/02/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');`

it will work please try

Answer (score 0):

Do this:-

Put `To_DATE` on `column name` rather than on values

```
   Select count(distinct f.CUSTOMER_ID) as agg from customerType f 
   INNER JOIN 
   customer t ON f.CUSTOMERID=t.CUSTOMERID where 
   f.type='VVIP' and (TO_DATE(t.BookingDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN 
   '10/01/2016' AND '10/02/2016');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t.customerid) AS agg
FROM customer t
LEFT JOIN customertype f
ON f.customerid=t.customerid
WHERE f.TYPE   ='VVIP'
AND to_date(t.bookingdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN to_date('01/24/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date('01/27/2016','MM/DD/YYYY');
```